# Wildcard SQL Query to search for specific text & replace

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to make an extremely wildcarded SQL query to find a specific URL across multiple sites (via phpMyAdmin) and replace them.

I've started off with the following, however it apparently isn't a valid SQL Query:

`SELECT * FROM *.* WHERE * LIKE '%https://website.com/er01%'`

I'm essentially trying to look in every single database, every single table, every single column. Once I've checked them I want to create a query to replace the URL with a new one (The URL would need to be replaced within the middle of a value as they're normally within the page content)

I am a novice with SQL so it's likely to be something obvious but I can't find a way to do what I want anywhere online.

Answer (score 2):

You need to run

```
show databases;
```

For each database, run

```
show tables;
```

For each table, run

```
desc <tablename>
```

And for each column, run

```
select * from databasename.tablename where columnname like '%https://website.com/er01%';
```

If there are too many possibilities to do so, then consider generating the queries.

And if you need all results, then consider unioning them.